# Django - How to query a related translated model?

Tags: django, django-models, django-parler

I have two models that are many to many related. Article and Tag models. Both are TranslateableModel using django-parler.

`models.py`

```
class Article(BaseModelMixin, TranslatableModel):
    translations = TranslatedFields(
        title=models.CharField(max_length=255),
        short_description=models.CharField(max_length=255),
        body=HTMLField(),
        slug=models.SlugField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True, unique=True),
    ),
    tags = models.ManyToManyField("Tag", related_name="articles")


class Tag(TranslatableModel):
    translations = TranslatedFields(
        slug=models.SlugField(max_length=55, blank=True, null=True),
        name=models.CharField(_("Tag name"), max_length=50),
    )
```

I would like to get all tags together with articles_count for the current language.

For example if a user comes to the page `/en/blog` I would like them to see tags together with the number of articles written in english for that tag. Something like `Django (7 articles), Ruby on rails (4 articles)` For django there might be 10 articles but only 7 are translated to english.

What I have is something like this:

```
Tag.objects.translated()
           .annotate(articles_count=(Count("articles__translations")))
```

But this gives me the count of total translations. If an article exists both in english and in french, it counts double.

How can I make it so that it gives me the number of articles only in the current language in a given tag?

Comment: Can you please share the related model(s)?

Comment: I've edited accordingly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can filter on the `language_code`, so:

```
from django.utils.translation import get_language

language = get_language()

Tag.objects.annotate(
    articles_count=Count(
        'articles__translations', 
        filter=Q(articles__translations__language_code__iexact=language)
    )
)
```

This will only retain `articles`s with the exact same language code. This thus means that if the language is `en-US`, it will not consider `en` to be valid.

You can retain only the language and not the country, and then filter with:

```
# culture-invariant languages

from django.utils.translation import get_language

language = get_language().split('-', 1)[0]

Tag.objects.annotate(
    articles_count=Count(
        'articles__translations', 
        filter=Q(articles__translations__language_code__istartswith=language)
    )
)
```

Comment: Great answer. Actually the key here was the word filter. I had tried this before asking the question but it did not work : `Tag.objects.articles_count=Count(Q(articles__translations__language_code__iexact=language))`